# ZF2 reading mail with attachments??

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I can't find any documentation about reading email attachments. Can anyone suggest something?

I am using `Zend\Mail\Storage\Imap` to read my emails text, but I cant find any methods to get attachments.

Answer (score 0):

ifYou can access the attachments using the Mime/Part package. You can firstly test that a message is multipart using `$message->isMultipart()`
You can then iterate a messages parts or access a specific part using `$part = $message->getPart($num);`
from there you can access the type of part, determine if its inline/attachements and so on.

Useful links:

see : http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.mail.attachments.html

see : http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.mime.part.html